# "Pythonic" for loop over integers 0 to k-1 except i

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I want to create a for loop that will go through the integers 0 to k-1, except for integer i.  (I'm comparing some lists of k items, and I don't need to compare item i in one list with item i in another list.)

I have a fairly easy way to do it, but I keep thinking there's a more "Pythonic", elegant way to do it.

What I'm doing is:

```
tocheck = range(k)
del(tocheck[i])
for j in tocheck:
```

It's easy enough, but one thing I like about Python is that it seems like there's always a clever one-line "Pythonic" trick for things like this.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain the overall problem some more?  Like what are you doing with the two lists and whatnot

Comment: From my understanding, what is opinion-based in this question is  the notion of __pythonic__, as it is basically asked for a pythonic version of a simple task. If this question is deemed as primarily opinion-based, then the entire stake of SO-question asking for pythonic - or in general idiomatic - ways of doing things should be deemed as well, I wonder if we really want to do that.

Comment: I think that this question can be factually answered with alternatives that are generally considered superior by the Python community without delving into the more opinion-based question of which is the *most* Pythonic.

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269443/1157100).

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps using `itertools.chain`

```
from itertools import chain

for j in chain(range(i), range(i+1, k)):
    # ...
```

Comment: Seems to be faster than loop with continue (at least for a test with k=1000

Comment: +1 I like that it avoids testing the value of `j` through each iteration, although for any non-trivial loop body, the performance gain is probably minimal.

Answer (score 4):

I think I would do one of:

```
for j in range(k):
    if j == i: continue
    ...code here...
```

or (fixed)

```
tocheck = range(k)
for j in tocheck[:i] + tocheck[i + 1:]:
    ...code here...
```

or

```
for j in range(i) + range(i + 1, k):
    ...code here...
```

Comment: The second one is a complicated way of writing `for j in []`. And `range` objects don't define `__add__`, so the third will only work in legacy 2.x versions, where it will be really slow.

Comment: The second example won't produce the correct output. It is always empty.

Comment: You guys are right of course, no idea what I was thinking, guess it's time to sleep...

Answer (score 4):

I think the most idiomatic way to leave a gap would be to skip in the for loop using `continue`.

```
i = 20
for j in range(50):
    if j==i:
        continue
    print j
```

Comment: I like that one best too, it also gives you a natural place to put the comment explaining why i needs to be skipped.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
for l in (j  for j in range(k) if j != i):
    ....
```

This uses a generator expression, which might be considered "pythonic", though the expression itself is a little confusing which might be considered inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be by just using iterators:

```
from itertools import chain
k = 10
l = range(k)
i = 2

print [el for el in iter(l[:i])] + [el for el in iter(l[i+1:])]
```

This works for any list `l`. In case of `l` just being some `range` you could omit the explicit definition of `l` and simply write:

```
print [el for el in xrange(i)] + [el for el in xrange(i+1,k)]
```

Comment: There's no need to explicitly call `iter` on the lists. The list comprehension is equivalent to just passing the `chain` iterator to `list`. This is otherwise the same answer that FatalError posted.

Comment: @chepner: Ah, sure, you are right! Silly me. I initially wanted to suggest the built-in `iter` method, as it allows to get an iterator over lists that are not as trivial as ranges, but the `chain` iterator makes the answer pointless, really. Can still use it with a shallow copy though, will change the answer.